# Почему метод выводит только последний элемент массива?

Tags: java

Само задание:
Есть класс Cat с полем имя (name, String).
Создать коллекцию HashMap.
Добавить в коллекцию 10 котов, в качестве ключа использовать имя кота.
Вывести результат на экран, каждый элемент с новой строки.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    String[] cats = new String[]{"васька", "мурка", "дымка", "рыжик", "серый", "снежок", "босс", "борис", "визя", "гарфи"};

    HashMap<String, Cat> map = addCatsToMap(cats);

    for (Map.Entry<String, Cat> pair : map.entrySet()) {
        System.out.println(pair.getKey() + " - " + pair.getValue());
    }
}


public static HashMap<String, Cat> addCatsToMap(String[] cats) {
    HashMap<String, Cat> map = new HashMap<String, Cat>();
    String name = "Vaskya";
    for(int i = 0; i < cats.length; i++) {
       map.put(name, new Cat(cats[i]));
    }
    return map;
}


public static class Cat {
    String name;

    public Cat(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return name != null ? name.toUpperCase() : null;
    }
}
```

Вывод:
Vaskya - ГАРФИ

Comment: ну вы все кладете под ключом `Vaskya`

Comment: А вы точно это сами писали?

Comment: Ну основная часть программы то конечно не мной написана,мне нужно сделать только то что по заданию надо

Answer (score 2):

> ```
> map.put(name, new Cat(cats[i]));
> ```

```
map.put(cats[i], new Cat(cats[i]));
```